# How to correctly create a nested attribute item from a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

Similar to this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised), I am trying to create a form for nested attributes. In my app, nodes can have questions attached to them. I want one form to be able to set the attributes for both nodes and questions. This is defined in the model:

node.rb

```
...
has_many :questions
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
```

I wasn't sure how exactly to create the form that would accept questions. This is it currently:

```
 <%= f.fields_for @node.questions do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'question_form', f: builder %>    
  <% end %>
```

The question form  then renders the relevant fields.

The Node controller is currently relying on the attributes being passed though correctly:
nodes_controller.rb

```
def new
@node = current_user.nodes.build 
//also tried building a question

def create
@node = current_user.nodes.new(params[:node])
@node.save... 
//anything else needed?
```

How do I get the form to successfully create questions?

Answer (score 0):

```
@node = current_user.nodes.new(params[:node])
```

should be

```
@node = current_user.nodes.create(params[:node])
```

Assuming the current_user variable is initialized, and that you've marked all attributes being saved from the form as 'mass assignable' using attr_accessible, it should work

Note that the `new` method just creates an object without saving it to the DB. `create` saves it to the DB.

Comment: Sorry, I had that code below, I updated it above. The node gets created, just not the question.

Comment: Please add the request params your controller is getting (you should get them in your development.log file or server console for the request on the `create` action.